# Elementary question about the limit $\big( 1 - \frac 1 {\sqrt n}\big )^n$, $n\to\infty$.

Tags: calculus, limits

When calculating the limit $L=\big( 1 - \frac 1 {\sqrt n}\big)^n$, $n\to\infty$, what allows me to do the following:

$$
L=\lim \left(\left(1-\frac {1}{\sqrt n}\right)^\sqrt{n} \right)^\sqrt{n}
$$

**As the term inside the outer parenthesis goes to $e^{-1}$, we have $L=\lim e^{-\sqrt n}=0$**.

It's like we're distributing the parenthesis somehow:

$$\lim \left(\left(1-\frac {1}{\sqrt n}\right)^\sqrt{n} \right)^\sqrt{n}=\lim \left(\lim\left (1-\frac {1}{\sqrt n}\right)^\sqrt{n} \right)^\sqrt{n}=\lim e^{-\sqrt n}$$

The question is: Why can we do this? Which property are we using?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If $n$ is large enough, then the inner power is close to $e^{-1}$, and in particular is less than $1/2$. And $(1/2)^{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I understand that, but I'm looking for a more rigorous proof of this property (and a generalization, if possible).

Comment: @JanEerland: OP is asking what justifies breaking up the expression into nested powers.

Comment: @limittroubled: If you accept the nesting uncritically *without* the limit, then just use the definition of the limit as $n \to \infty$.  First show that the inner power is less than $1/2$.  Then, let $N = -\lg \varepsilon$, and show that for any $n > N$, the expression is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @BrianTung What is $\operatorname{lg}\epsilon$?

Comment: @limittroubled: Sorry, that's a bit cryptic; $\lg x$ is a somewhat abbreviation for $\log_2 x$. Its code is just "\lg x".  As it happens, the inner power is also always less than $1/e$, so we could just as easily let $N = -\ln \varepsilon$.

Comment: @limittroubled: As to rigour, the outline I gave can be more or less mechanically turned into an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof. As to generalization, a direct one has been given by k.stem. There is further generalization possible, and yours is a very good question. It is all too easy to use roughly similar reasoning and get wrong answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the following statement.

Let $(a_n)$ be a converging sequence of non-negative real numbers with $\lvert \lim_{n → ∞} a_n \rvert < 1$. Furthermore, let $(e_n)$ be an unbounded, increasing sequence. Then $({a_n}^{e_n})$ converges to zero.

*Proof idea*. Let $a = \lim_{n → ∞} a_n$. Let $K > 1$ be a real number. Then $({a_n}^K)$ converges to $a^K$ by limit theorems. Since $e_n > K$ for large enough $n$, almost all members of $({a_n}^{e_n})$ are smaller than $a^K$, so both limes inferior and limes superior of the sequence $({a_n}^{e_n})$ lie within the interval $[0..a^K]$.

Because $K$ was arbitrary and $\lvert a \rvert < 1$, the sequence must converge to zero.

Comment: Using your notation ${a_n}^{e_n}=\left(1-\frac {1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n$,  we **do not** have $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert\lim_{n → ∞} a_n\rvert< 1$ here. I'm afraid the above result as stated **does not** apply.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Hey, Olivier: I think, nine years ago, I meant $e_n = \sqrt n$ here, and $a_n= (1 - \frac 1 {\sqrt n})^{\sqrt n} \overset{n→∞} \longrightarrow \mathrm{e}^{-1}$, with $\lvert \mathrm e^{-1} \rvert < 1$. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

One may use, as $x \to 0$, the classic Taylor expansion:
$$
\ln (1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+O(x^3)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
n\ln \left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)=n \times\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\right)\right)=-\sqrt{n}-\frac12+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$ then, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left(1-\frac {1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n=e^{-\sqrt{n}-1/2}\left(1+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right) \to 0.
$$