# When does $\lim_n ({a_n})^{b_n} =\lim_n \left (\lim_m a_m^{c_m}\right)^{d_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $a_n\to a$, $b_n\to b$. $a,b\in\Bbb R\cup\{\pm \infty\}$.

Suppose further that $b_n=c_nd_n$.

What are some conditions required on $b_n,c_n$ and $d_n$ to guarantee that the following equation  $$\lim_{n\to\infty} ({a_n})^{b_n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left (\lim_{m\to \infty} a_m^{c_m}\right)^{d_n}$$

holds?

This is generalization of this question: [Elementary question about the limit $\big( 1 - \frac 1 {\sqrt n}\big )^n$, $n\to\infty$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681772/elementary-question-about-the-limit-big-1-frac-1-sqrt-n-big-n-n-to)

Comment: Do you have any information about the convergance of either $c_n$ or $d_n$?

Comment: @christina_g Well, I'm looking for 'minimal' conditions, thus not assuming anything about either, unless necessary.

Comment: I would suggest to start adding conditions to make it true, and then try and find which ones can be reduced or replaced without messing with the result