# Limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n$ as n tends to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n}$. It looks pretty easy, so I think there's probably something simple I'm missing, because I can't seem to figure out where to even start. I've tried some basic algebraic manipulation but it doesn't seem to help much. I know the sequence diverges to infinity from typing it into WolframAlpha, but I don't know how to show that it's unbounded.

I'm trying to do it without using L'Hospital's rule or Bernoulli's inequality. Other Calc 1 methods are fair game.

Comment: Just use the good old $\exp/\log$-trick and taylor expansion...

Comment: Do you know what $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is?

Comment: Or simply $$\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)^{\sqrt n}\geqslant2$$

Comment: Write as $((1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^{\sqrt{n}})^{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: possible duplicate :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1681772/156150

Comment: See also:
[The limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2904957) or
[Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2046856).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a way without using Bernoulli directly but using the binomial formula only:
$\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n= 1 + \binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt n} + \binom{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^2 + \cdots +  \binom{n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n \stackrel{n>1}{>} 1 + \binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt n} = 1+\sqrt{n}$

Comment: If use of Bernoulli's Inequality is prohibited, then use of the binomial theorem is also likely to be prohibited.

Comment: I'm allowed to use the binomial theorem, actually. Thank you all for your answers :) I'm going to accept this one as it's the simplest to understand given the tools I have to work with but having different perspectives is always a great thing.

Comment: @Cassiterite Bernoulli's Inequality is actually quite a bit more elementary than the binomial theorem.  In fact, the first two terms of the binomial theorem for $(1+x)^n$ are $1$ and $nx$.

Answer (score 4):

Bernoulli's Inequality gives

$$\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)^n\ge1+\sqrt n\to \infty$$

Comment: That's nice and simple, unfortunately I can't use Bernoulli's inequality either. Should have mentioned it in the question, sorry, I've updated it

Comment: Very nice and direct way!

Comment: @gimusi Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Cassiterite Are you permitted to use the inequalities $\log(x)\ge \frac{x-1}{x}$ and $e^x\ge 1+x$?  If so, then we have $$\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)}\ge e^{\frac{n}{1+\sqrt n}}\ge 1+\frac{n}{1+\sqrt n}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^{\sqrt n}\right]^{\frac n {\sqrt n}}\ge2^{\frac n {\sqrt n}}\to \infty$$

or as an alternative

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)}\sim e^{\frac n {\sqrt n}-\frac12}\to \infty$$

Answer (score 3):

As $n\to\infty$, $$\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)^{\sqrt n}\to e$$ and $e^{\sqrt n}$ is divergent since $e>1$.